Issue with "The job is using protected resource(s) for which checks have not been evaluated" error in Azure DevOps CD pipeline
I'm facing an issue with my Continuous Deployment (CD) in Azure DevOps. In my CD pipeline YAML, I'm using multiple environments: one for non-production environment and the other for production environment. While the non-production environment works fine, when I try to trigger the production environment, which has certain approvals set up for the service connection and Azure DevOps environment, I'm encountering the following error:

#[error]The job is using protected resource(s) for which checks have not been evaluated endpoint: [service endpoint name]. For more
details, refer to https://aka.ms/pipelinechecks.

Could someone help me diagnose this issue and suggest how to resolve it? Is there something I need to configure or change in my pipeline to avoid this error?

you might need to provide the details of the YAML and Approvals and checks set on the resources.

When you reference the protected resources in the YAML pipeline, are you using any variables to pass the names/IDs of the resources? If so, what expressions do you use to reference the variables ? Did you try to hard-code them in the YAML pipeline to see if the issue exists?

How exactly Azure Devops pipeline evaluates  Service Connection approvals for a specific stage/job?.  How I understand it will show up before pipeline trigger stage when you have reference in any job/task inside our stage

The Pre-Checks and Pre-Approvals will be promoted before the stage starts running. As mentioned above,  you can provide more details of the Approvals and checks and the YAML configured in your project if you want helps for further investigation on the issue. @komluk

Alright, I've resolved the problem. It appears the issue was straightforward, as someone mistakenly altered the syntax within the parameters. It proved challenging to detect since the YAML validator indicated everything was correct.

It's great that you can fix the issue. Can you provide more details about how you fix the issue? This could be also helpful for other people who are looking for a solution of the issue issues. @komluk
